# Python script send out more emails that it supposed to send

Tags: python, email, raspberry-pi, smtp

I tried the solution for the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301172), but it didn't help.

Part of my python script sends out email to recipients. When I run the code in my Pycharm it sends out exactly 3 emails which is the number of email addresses for my test case and the number which it suppose to send out. However, when I try to run it on my raspberry pi it randomly sends out the emails and I cannot find a pattern of the difference number of emails that it sends out.

So, there is a list called 'toAddrs' which saves the email address of recipients. I tried the following two ways once using a for loop and once without a for loop. But both of these send an arbitrary number of emails.

```
#subject, fromAddr, mainbody and password are already defined
msg = MIMEMultipart('')
msg.attach(MIMEText(mainbody, 'plain'))
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = fromAddr
msg['To'] = toAddrs
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromAddr, password)

for i in range(len(toAddrs)):
        server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddrs[i], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

and another one is:

```
#subject, fromAddr, mainbody and password are already defined
msg = MIMEMultipart('')
msg.attach(MIMEText(mainbody, 'plain'))
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = fromAddr
msg['To'] = ' ,'.join(toAddrs)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromAddr, password)
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddrs, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I cannot find what might be wrong. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: In your second example, `', '.join(toAddress) is a string of the form `'email1@website.com, email2@website.com, ..., emailn@website.com'`, where there are *n* emails in the string. So this just sends the email to *everyone* every time an email is sent.

Comment: In your first example, what exactly does `join(toAddress)` do? You must have defined a `join` function somewhere in your code, or else you would be getting a `NameError`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python SMTP: emails being combined into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301172/python-smtp-emails-being-combined-into-one)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help @snakecharmerb

Comment: I added the other parts of the code if it helps @Will

Comment: @Joel Can you explain more, I think it shouldn't.

About the first example it was a typo and I fixed it.

Comment: Try calling `print(', '.join(toAddress))` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Joel so you're saying if there is n recipients, so there is going to be n^2 emails send out altogether? If so, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Luna2 does the n^2 pattern match what you are seeing? Does your code call the code blocks you posted more than once?

Comment: @Will No I only want to send n emails. For example if there is email1 and email2, I want to send one email for each of these two emails. OR even sending one single email CCing or BCCing will also work for my purpose. For a list of 3 emails when I run this with my PyCharm it send out only 3 email, which I need. But when I have the same list and code while running it on my raspberry pi, it sends an arbitrary number of emails. Sometimes it keeps sending out exactly 10 ( 9+1 !) emails but it is not a fixed number!

Comment: If you run it with the same inputs does it produce the same results? Can you find any pattern to the number of emails sent? (or post a few sample input->emails sent and their distribution among adresses so we can spot the pattern?)